# How do I check to see if a cell contains a phrase from a defined range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I check to see if a cell contains a phrase from a defined range of cells?

I have a column filled with keywords, if one of the keywords is mentioned in a Column A, I want Column B to display FALSE, otherwise TRUE.